# Why people use style on React direct to the file on File.js? Why not just on index.html?

Tags: reactjs

I see many people on my learning or developer use react always make the css file direct to the App.js or component on React, like this:

```
require('./style/main.css');
```

or this

```
import styles from './style/main.css';
```

Why we must do this? Why not linking on head of index.html?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question has nothing to do with react-native.

React native is a framework that was developed by Facebook that lets you build mobile apps using only JavaScript. It uses the same design as React, letting you compose a rich mobile UI from declarative components.
You can read about it more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

However, judging by what you have written, they're probably using `require` and `import` just to make you get used to the fact that you're going to them a lot in your project. You can still add your stylesheet inside your HTML document normally though.

A small basic example.

**JS:**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div id="div">Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #div {
      background: #FFF
    }
  </style>
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Raymond had said in his answer, your question does not apply for react-native as there is no html in react-native.

If you are just learning react, chances are you are bootstrapping your react project with create-react-app. You can include the css in the html and it will work just fine. However, importing static assets (images, css, etc) has a few advantages, which are (quoting from the [documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder)):

1. Scripts and stylesheets get minified and bundled together, thus reducing the network payload.
2. Missing files cause compilation errors instead of 404 errors.
3. Result filenames include content hashes so you don’t need to worry about browsers caching their old versions. This will ensure that the assets are always 'fresh'.

Comment: This is the correct answer I think, because I search on Google, no anyone people discuss about this topic. Thanks man for your answer. It's clear for me.

Comment: @FuaditMuhammad Feel free to accept my answer too 

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, why do people do this...?
React is a JavaScript centric library. In that the JS code defines the component (or application) and from there all the dependencies are declared, including assets. The HTML is really a secondary concern, and just provides the mounting point for the app.

If you use a bundling tool like webpack you can declare component and application asset dependencies inside your code. The bundler will parse these files are add them to the bundle (as external files). This is good practice as it allows components to be self contained - you import the code and all dependent files are automatically added to your bundle. Via plugins, the bundling tool also has a chance to do some processing on the file, like adding browser prefixes to CSS attributes. With modular CSS this approach will become more and more common.

Comment: Yes, I got it on frontendmasters.com. Yeah, I didn't realize this before. Thank you so much.